# Not able to install requests on cygwin - ImportError: No module named _io

Tags: python, cygwin, python-requests

When I try the following command

```
pip install requests
```

I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2307, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2013, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 8, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
    import io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: No module named _io
```

But when I tried to check the `env` using the following command

```
env python
```

I could see that it is running from python 2.7 only

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09)
[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

So in the interactive command line I tried the following

```
>>> import _io
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _io
```

Comment: What does `import io` do? You might also want to have a look at http://bugs.python.org/issue9665

Comment: I quiet do not understand what is given there. Basically I am trying to install requests module

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your Anti-Virus program deleted `io.py`. I just had to reinstall `python` on cygwin and try installing the program with the Anti-Virus turned off. I successfully installed `request` this way.

Comment: Sorry. caught up with work. Havent tried yet. Will let you know once I am done with it

Answer (score 0):

Your pip has broken or conflict with two package installation easy_install vs pip.

1) upgrade or re install with easy_install pip

will solve the problem, if you have other issue with your virtual env due to 14.04 upgrade then look at the question here.[similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176697/importerror-no-module-named-io-in-ubuntu-14-04/23430316#23430316)