# ImportError: No module named _io in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I just fresh installed ubuntu 14.04LTS and i am trying to use pip but i am getting the following traceback:

```
(nlmanagement)psychok7@Ultrabook:~/code/work/nlmanagement$ pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/psychok7/code/work/venv/nlmanagement/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/home/psychok7/code/work/venv/nlmanagement/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/psychok7/code/work/venv/nlmanagement/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2279, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/psychok7/code/work/venv/nlmanagement/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1989, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/home/psychok7/code/work/venv/nlmanagement/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.backwardcompat import walk_packages, console_to_str
  File "/home/psychok7/code/work/venv/nlmanagement/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/backwardcompat.py", line 77, in <module>
    from urllib2 import URLError, HTTPError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 79, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: No module named _io
```

any ideas?? i have tried `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` and `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608236/eclipse-and-google-app-engine-importerror-no-module-named-sysconfigdata-nd-u

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Your virtualenv became corrupt due to diffs in the Python system lib.

Best choice is to reinstall your virtualenv:

```
$ deactivate
$ rmvirtualenv nlmanagement
$ mkvirtualenv nlmanagement
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: why do i have these diffs? because of the upgrade?

Comment: @psychok7 yep, the system upgrade probably replaced some libraries.

Comment: Bingo! I didn't even think of the virtualenv getting stale from the upgrade.

Comment: It tells me that `rmvirtualenv: command not found`.  Do I need to be in a specific directory or something?  Also, what/where is `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Sure, but this is a big hammer, when just copying the new 2.7 binary to the existing env is sufficient (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24191303/143804).

Comment: @ire_and_curses I prefer to have a proper clean virtualenv from scratch. Why is this a big hammer? Nothing is lost.

Comment: That depends on how expensive your virtualenv is to recreate. In my specific case, the installation is only semi-automated through requirements.txt. There is a manual licensing step, and a manual configuration step. Also, I depend on scipy, among other things. Building scipy from scratch takes many minutes.

Comment: Just came across this answer, and thought I'd add that your suggestion depends on the mkvirtualenv scripts being installed, and that you're suggesting someone destroy their virtualenv before freezing their requirements file.

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem. This happened in Ubuntu - 14.04 and Virtual environment's Python version - 2.7.3

After spending a day in debugging, posting my answer here, hope it helps for future visitors.

I found that `io.py` is invoking `_io` module. I think `_io` module is internal to the interpreter, so, just replacing the `python` binary in the environment alone with the newer version should fix.

(In my case, Cloudera Manager 5.x Agent's virtualenv on ubuntu 14.04 was using python interpreter 2.7.3, replaced it with 2.7.6.

```
echo "Using " && python2.7 --version
mv myenv/bin/python myenv/bin/python.bak;
cp `which python2.7` myenv/bin/python
```

When a new virtualenv is created, it uses updated python binary from the system. Hence, that explains the accepted answer in the thread.

Comment: I thought the whole point of virtualenv was to wall off the python and libraries from the OS.  Why would the system python change affect anything?

Comment: After trying this I get "ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd", due to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466

Comment: That is a great question. Though the virtualenv wall off the python stuff, the `_io` issue is with the native libraries of interpreter itself which are plausibly not isolated, shared from system. I think, in ubuntu 14.04 some of system libraries are restructured, so the older python(2.7.3 - which with ubuntu12.04) did not work. When I checked with the newer python that came along with ubuntu14.04(just be dropping into console and do `import io`) it worked.

Comment: I had to remove `myenv/bin/python` before copy. ```rm myenv/bin/python;cp `which python` myenv/bin/python```. Thanks!

Comment: This is the only answer on this page that actually worked for me (tried them all). This upgraded the python interpreter from python 2.7.3 in the virtual-env to 2.7.6.  I'm not using Cloudera manager BTW, just a vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 where the virtual env originated in 12.04 (and git cloned on 14.04). Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is easy and worked for me (but not the others provided). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need to delete the virtual environment.

Just follow these steps.

1. Let's say your virtual environment name is "mydev" and you are using `virtualenvwrapper`, do

   ```
   cd $WORKON_HOME
   virtualenv mydev
   ```

   The above command just upgrades the link to the python executable without losing any package. Without `virtualenvwrapper`, `$WORKON_HOME` might not be defined; then you need to change to the parent directory of the virtualenv.
2. outside virtualenv, if your pip is not working, then just

   ```
   easy_install pip
   ```

   will resolve the issue.

Comment: Trying #1 I get 'OSError: Command python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])'

Comment: pip was not working.  I eventually solved it with a symlink per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading my ubuntu server to 14.04, I also have this kind of problem while executing pip

```
ImportError: No module named _io
```

Then I found out simply reinstall `virtualenv` can solve this issue!

`sudo pip install virtualenv --upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

One cause of this is a bad "pip".  See:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1373254

And/or it can be a problem with virtualenv:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466
Where the recommended workaround is:

```
  cd /usr/lib/python2.7
  ln -s plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.py .
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the python version in your corrupted virtualenv.

Do this:

1. Create a new Virtualenv

   ```
   mkvirtualenv MyNewTestEnv
   ```
2. Locate "python" (in my case the virtualenvs are located in the home directory)

   ```
   cd ~/.virtualenvs/MyNewTestEnv/bin
   ```
3. Copy "python" from the new virtualenv into your corrupted virtualenv

   ```
   cp ~/.virtualenvs/MyNewTestEnv/bin/python ~/.virtualenvs/<yourCorruptedEnv>/bin
   ```

That's it. Now your CorruptedEnv should be fixed.

Comment: what is `mkvirtualenv `? I can't find that package on ubuntu

Comment: checkout Virtualenvwrapper!

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed different python versions. You must reference your python

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 myenv
```

or

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.x myenv
```

Answer (score 0):

**This workaround applies to SuSE 12.2**
Downloaded python and installed it with ./configure and make install to defult /usr/local folder

Installed pip and virtualenv

When trying to create python virtual env

```
*linux-t69c:/nkadic # virtualenv -p python venv2*
**ImportError: No module named _struct**
or (if manually setting PYTHONPATH)
**ImportError: No module named _io**
```

Here is the workaround:

Check default sys.path python (do not change default PYTHONPATH)

check if there are libs dir /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload exists

if not, create symlink to existing lib64 path:

```
linux-t69c:/nkadic # ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/  
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
linux-t69c:/nkadic # ls -ltr /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Aug 12 21:06 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload -> 
/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/
```

After this workaround "virtualenv -p python venv2" works

```
linux-t69c:/nkadic # virtualenv -p python venv2
Already using interpreter /usr/local/bin/python
PYTHONHOME is set.  You *must* activate the virtualenv before using it
New python executable in /nkadic/venv2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
linux-t69c:/nkadic #
```