# No module named tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

I installed tweepy successfully but at the time that I want to import it, it appears to me that I don't have it

I'm new to this and I don't know a lot of things, hope you can help me. I'm using macOS
and python 3.9.0

```
%`pip freeze
    
 tweepy==3.9.0`
```

then:

```
python my_twitter_bot.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_twitter_bot.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tweepy 
ImportError: No module named tweepy
```

Comment: what does `python -m pip freeze | grep tweepy` show?

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431002/unable-to-import-tweepy-module

Comment: How did you install tweepy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import tweepy module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431002/unable-to-import-tweepy-module)

Answer (score 0):

Do you install the library in your global or Python environment? If you're not using environment, I'll suggest you go with Python environment.

1. Make sure you already install `virtualenv`

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
```

2. Go to your Documents folder (or anywhere), then run this. FYI, `env` in the command would be your folder name. You will access your environment using that name

```
python3 -m venv env
```

3. Make sure your in correct path and run this command to active the environment

```
source env/bin/activate
```

4. Then, you can install the library

```
pip install tweepy
```

5. Try import the library

```
$ python3
>>> import tweepy
```

Answer (score 0):

you're probably using a version of python that isn't supported by the module. Try using later versions. the same thing happened to me with the keyboard module, I had to switch to 3.8