# ImportError: No module named 'pandas' (inside virtualenv)

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-venv

I created a virtual environment named quora for python. 
I installed wheel and then pandas as instructed. 
I cant get pandas to work for some reason.
Can someone help me.
I have tried all the other solutions available to similar questions on this website. Still no use.

```
(quora) (jessie)griffith@localhost:~/environments$ sudo pip install wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
(quora) (jessie)griffith@localhost:~/environments$ sudo pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas)
```

---

```
(quora) (jessie)griffith@localhost:~/environments$ python getdata.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getdata.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: Linking you to a dupe. It should help.

Comment: I tried following the answers on that question. Still no help. It is running outside the virtual environment, but does not work inside. I used yolk to check for installed packages. It says pandas is installed inside the environment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27451629/7976758) in a virtualenv — `sudo pip install` installs packages into global `site-packages`, not in virtualenv.

Either install pandas in the virtual environment (`pip install` after activating venv) or enable access to the global packages (recreate venv with option `--system-site-packages` or use command `toggleglobalsitepackages` from virtualenvwrapper).

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem in a virtualenv with pip3 and pandas, tried all these previous answers, none of which actually work.  but you can use easy_install pandas.  et voilà.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by deleting my virtualenv directory and creating a new environment.

Comment: Same issue. had something messed up or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the answers before in my **archlinux** machine but none worked. But [this post](https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/) from [Nikolai Janakiev](https://janakiev.com) helped me find a good solution.

## Solution

Don't forget to first activate the virtual env, mine is named `.venv`:

```
$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) $ python3 -m pip install ipykernel
```

Pick any arbitrary name and replace with `NEW_KERNEL`, this shows up in your jupyter notebook with the same name:

```
(.venv) $ python3 -m ipykernel install --name=NEW_KERNEL
```

And you're done!

## Creating Virtual Environments

If you're not already familiar with setting up a virtual environment, here is [the official guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments).

Let's suppose you want to create a virtual environment under the name `.venv`. I use the `.` prefix to hide it by default.

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv
$ source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) $ python3 -m pip install pandas
```

And voila! You have access to the `pandas` package in `.venv` environment.

## Using Virtual Environments in Jupyter Notebooks

If you're wondering how to activate the virtual environment in a `jupyter-notebook`, just follow the **Solution** section above, and then open up the notebook, and click on `Kernel` then `Change Kernel` to `NEW_KERNEL` or the name you picked in the **Solution** section.

Answer (score 0):

Check "which python" you are running using that command. You may need to export PATH to the python env instead of your default python which might be /usr/lib/bin. It might be installed in your quora env but the python that is being picked up is different and that doesn't have pandas

Answer (score 0):

go to pyvenv.cfg and change

```
include-system-site-packages = false
```

to

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```