# Install dependencies only in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

I need to freeze my dependencies inside of virtualenv. As in virtualenv I have flask web application list of requirements should look like this:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
Werkzeug==0.9.6
html5lib==0.999
itsdangerous==0.24
mote==0.0.3
ndg-httpsclient==0.3.2
pyasn1==0.1.7
requests==2.4.3
twython==3.1.2
urllib3==1.9.1
virtualenv==15.1.0
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

But when I try to freeze it by doing:

```
source venv/bin/activate
sudo sh -c 'sudo pip freeze > require.txt' # baceuse after simple  sudo pip freeze > requir.txt I am getting this error -bash: requir.txt: Permission denied
```

I am getting this list:

```
Cap1xxx==0.1.3
ExplorerHAT==0.4.2
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Email==1.4.4
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
MySQL-python==1.2.3
Pillow==2.6.1
RPi.GPIO==0.6.3
RTIMULib==7.2.1
Werkzeug==0.9.6
argparse==1.2.1
automationhat==0.0.4
blinker==1.3
blinkt==0.1.0
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.2
dropbox==8.6.0
drumhat==0.0.5
envirophat==0.0.6
fourletterphat==0.0.2
gpiozero==1.4.0
html5lib==0.999
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
lxkeymap==0.1
mcpi==0.1.1
microdotphat==0.1.3
mote==0.0.3
motephat==0.0.2
ndg-httpsclient==0.3.2
numpy==1.8.2
phatbeat==0.0.2
pianohat==0.0.5
picamera==1.13
picraft==1.0
pifacecommon==4.2.1
pifacedigitalio==3.1.0
piglow==1.2.4
pigpio==1.35
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyasn1==0.1.7
pygame==1.9.2a0
pygobject==3.14.0
pyinotify==0.9.4
pyserial==2.6
python-apt==0.9.3.12
rainbowhat==0.0.2
requests==2.18.4
scrollphat==0.0.7
scrollphathd==1.0.1
sense-emu==1.0
sense-hat==2.2.0
six==1.8.0
skywriter==0.0.7
smbus==1.1
sn3218==1.2.7
spidev==3.0
touchphat==0.0.1
twython==3.1.2
urllib3==1.22
virtualenv==15.1.0
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

which as you can see contains all installed packages and many of them are not connected to my flask web application like for instance `numpy==1.8.2` or `RPi.GPIO==0.6.3` despite the fact I am doing it inside of virtualenv..

So, is there a way to get list of dependencies which are bundled only with my flask app..?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use `sudo` with virtualenvs (and there is no need for it in any case)

Comment: With the sh command you start a new shell, which does not know about the previous  activate command at all.

Comment: Achso! That's the point! Thank you! How to handle it if I am getting 'permission error' ?

Comment: With the sh command you start a new shell (a children process of the original), which does not know about the previous activate command at all. Why don't you change the owner or permission of the require.txt files (chown or chmod)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'pandas' (inside virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666097/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-inside-virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said in comments just do

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

`sudo` is not needed with virtualenv

Comment: In this case I am getting an error: 
-bash: permission denied. 

After changing rights of the .txt file and doing this command the whole file is empty

Comment: You don’t need `sh -c`

Comment: Yes, I got it. By 'this command' I meant your command: pip freeze > requirements.txt

Comment: Is pip owned by root? You may need to change perms

Comment: Hm.. Actually I installed all packages by root.. Maybe

Comment: You can check this with `ls -l venv`. If you created it as root you should see something like `drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 jan   19 15:33 bin` and so on. There is a way to change the owner of the entire virtualenv like this `sudo chown -R yourusername venv` Or better, if you the username john at your computer, you probably have a group name john as well so `sudo chown -R john.john venv` is even better (the second john is the group).

Answer (score -2):

You can change the permisson the files as

```
 chmod 664 require.txt
```

and change the owner of the file to yours as

```
 chown myusername require.txt
```

(If you don't know your user name, you can ask with the command

```
 whoami
```

however usually it is in the command prompt.)

Comment: Yes, the file require.txt is empty after that