# virtualenv : pip doesn't install inside the environment

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, virtualenv

Here I am trying to install some module(consider numpy) in virtualenv environment cv. I trying install it with,

```
sudo pip3 install numpy
```

it gets inside my normal environment but not the one i created using virtualenv. I keep getting

```
File "sample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

It works fine in my normal environment. The installed files exist under my /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages but couldn't find it under .virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I refered couple similar problems and tried it but none worked. I even tried deactivating the env and creating a new one. Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks in advance.

Note: I did activate the environment. When I tried installing again, it says,

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

It is checking in the normal environment lib folder, not in the virtualenv.

Comment: Did you activate the virtual environment then install `numpy`?

Comment: of course, I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'pandas' (inside virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666097/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-inside-virtualenv)

Comment: Don't use `sudo` in a virtualenv — `sudo pip install` installs packages into global `site-packages`, not in virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and the issue was that I had `python` referring to python 2.7. When you create the virtualenv, the default python interpreter is `/usr/bin/python`. If you then install with `pip3` it tries to install in the default python 3 location. The solution was to specify:

```
virtualenv <venv-name> --py /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the pip install command inside an activated virtualenv ?

This link tells you how: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/

You can also refer to: [How to leave/exit/deactivate a python virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990754/how-to-leave-exit-deactivate-a-python-virtualenv?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
source .virtualenvs/cv/bin/activate
```

Now try installing libraries with pip.

When you are done working on this project deactivate the virtualenvs with `deactivate` command.