# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

I'm running my Jupyter Notebook in a virtual environment.

I've installed pandas in it with `pip3 install pandas` (I've tried with `sudo python3 -m pip install pandas` in other venv and without `sudo`, too, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666097/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-inside-virtualenv) other post suggests)

I've tried doing
`export PYTHONPATH=/home/myuser/Notebooks/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages`

but the error remains (I've restarted the notebook kernel, as well). Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'pandas' (inside virtualenv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666097/importerror-no-module-named-pandas-inside-virtualenv)

Comment: No. I've tried all of that and still doesn't work

Comment: @Palinuro [This new answer worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72657392/6474744)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Installing packages from Notebook running this cell:

```
! pip install --user numpy
! pip install --user pandas
```

changing the kernel reselecting Python3 in `Kernel -> Change kernel` and restarting it, the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your are not installing pandas into the virtual environment correctly.

If you have access to a shell, you can possibly `cd` into the `.venv` folder.
Then you can run `source ./bin/activate`, after this there should be a `(.venv)` prefix in your shell window.

Now run your `pip3 install pandas` commando once again, this time it will install pandas into your virtual environment instead of your global python environment.

Comment: That's what I did. The installation and the notebook were running the venv

Comment: Ah I see, well I see you luckily solved the problem already! :)