# apt-get install always returns error "ImportError: No module named _io"

Tags: python-2.7, dpkg

I cannot use 'apt-get install' at all due to this kind of error:

```
me@me:~$ sudo apt-get install unzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unzip is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  lsb-release
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "ko_KR.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up gconf2 (2.28.1-6) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/gconf-schemas", line 8, in <module>
    import sys,os,os.path,shutil,tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
ImportError: No module named _io
dpkg: error processing gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

unzip package is just an example, I cannot install any packages because of the same error.
I found a similar question from stackoverflow : [ImportError: No module named _io in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176697/importerror-no-module-named-io-in-ubuntu-14-04) but I think this is not a proper solution for me. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: It says "unzip is already the newest version." - is it?  Is unzip installed now or not?

Comment: @JohnZwinck oh I'm sorry, I thought it was not installed due to that error... actually the package was installed. But are those errors okay to occur?