# Python import modulr _io error

Tags: python, ubuntu, cloudera-manager

I have 3 python versions. `python2.7 python3 python3.4`

I don't have any experience in Python. I haven't used it before. This error exists as part of `cluster setup via cloudera manager`.

**ERROR**

```
 ..........
 >> import mimetools 
  >> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module> 
 >> import tempfile 
 >> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module> 
 >> import io as _io 
 >> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module> 
 >> import _io 
 >>ImportError: No module named _io 
 >>Traceback (most recent call last): 
 >> File "/usr/lib/cmf/agent/src/cmf/agent.py", line 8, in <module> 
 >> import avro.ipc 
 >> File "/usr/lib/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/avro-1.6.3-py2.7.egg/avro/ipc.py", line 19, in <module> 
 >> import httplib 
 >> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 79, in <module> 
 >> import mimetools 
 >> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module> 
 >> import tempfile 
 >> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module> 
 >> import io as _io 
 >> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module> 
 >> import _io 
 >>ImportError: No module named _io
```

**Tried**

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176697/importerror-no-module-named-io-in-ubuntu-14-04)

I really don't know where to run accepted answers' commands. And Second answer, which has 30 votes, I tried. It says "cp: ‘/usr/bin/python2.7’ and ‘/usr/bin/python’ are the same file". Anyone please help me?

It's a new ubuntu OS. Not even upgradation.

Answer (score 0):

If you open a terminal window, you can call python two ways:

```
python
```

in which case it will call python 2.7. Or:

```
python3
```

in which case, I suspect it will  call python 3.4. You normally cannot have two different python3 version operational at the same time. (And I'd suggest removing one of them).

On the other hand, if you install a module, it will install in just one of the Pythons (may depend on which tool you use). So, if you install _io in python 2, it will not be accessible to python3. Some modules may not even be available for both Python flavors.

You can easily try this out. Try importing the module in each of the Pythons:

```
$ python
>>> import io
??? 
>>> Ctl^D

$ python3
>>> import io
```

Now, `io` is a system module, so it *should* be available. If it isn't, then probably there is confusion in Python3 about where it has to find the module (probably caused by your two versions of Python3).

Now, I'm not familiar with Cloudera. If Cloudera runs Python in a virtual environment, then the confusion might be even greater (and there was probably an installation problem).

Comment: Yes, It's a installation problem only,